# In Ruby, What structures can a `rescue` statement be nested in

Tags: ruby, syntax, error-handling

In ruby to catch an error one uses the `rescue` statement.  generally this statement occurs between `begin` and `end`. One can also use a `rescue` statement as part of a block (`do ... end`) or a method (`def ... end`).  My question is what other structures (loop, while, if, ...)  if any will rescue nest within?

Comment: `do ... end` blocks can't be rescued from without an explicit `begin ... end`.

Comment: Since [ruby 2.5](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/0ec889d7ed) `do ... end`  blocks can be rescued without an explicit `begin ... end`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can only use rescue in two cases:

- Within a `begin ... end` block

  ```
  begin
    raise
  rescue 
    nil
  end
  ```
- As a statement modifier

  ```
  i = raise rescue nil
  ```

Function, module, and class bodies (thanks Jörg) are implicit `begin...end` blocks, so you can rescue within any function without an explicit `begin`/`end`.

```
    def foo
      raise
    rescue
      nil
    end
```

The block form takes an optional list of parameters, specifying which exceptions (and descendants) to `rescue`:

```
    begin
      eval string
    rescue SyntaxError, NameError => boom
      print "String doesn't compile: " + boom
    rescue StandardError => bang
      print "Error running script: " + bang
    end
```

If called inline as a statement modifier, or without argument within a `begin`/`end` block, rescue will catch [`StandardError` and its descendants](http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2006/09/06/rubys-exception-hierarchy).

Here's the [1.9 documentation on `rescue`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/files/keywords_rb.html#M000030).

Comment: `module` and `class` bodies are implicit `begin` blocks, too.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: as are `do ... end` blocks and `def ... end` method definitions. IS there anything else that is an implicit `begin`?  `while`, `case`, or `if` for example?

Comment: @john - do...end isn't an implicit begin...end.

Comment: I suggest adding the comment above about do...end to the answer... that is really what I was looking for.

Comment: Although not very well documented, as of ruby 2.5 `rescue` works in regular `do`/`end` blocks (not in-line blocks `{...}` though). [commit](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/0ec889d7ed)

Answer (score 12):

As said in [recent comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524740/in-ruby-what-structures-can-a-rescue-statement-be-nested-in#comment106635101_2525334), response has changed [since Ruby 2.5](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/0ec889d7ed).

`do ... end` blocks are now implicit `begin ... end` blocks; like module, class and method bodies.

In-line blocks `{...}` still can't.

Comment: my favorite is `each` blocks