# Why does this rescue syntax work?

Tags: ruby, rescue

Ok so I have this method of an application I am working with and it works in production. My question why does this work? Is this new Ruby syntax?

```
def edit
  load_elements(current_user) unless current_user.role?(:admin)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @user }   
    format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
    format.html
  end

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  respond_to_not_found(:json, :xml, :html)
end
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542672/how-does-one-use-rescue-in-rails-without-the-begin-and-end-block

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`rescue`s do not need to be tied to an explicit `begin` when they're in a method, that's just the way the syntax is defined. For examples, see [#19 here](http://www.rubyinside.com/21-ruby-tricks-902.html) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524740/in-ruby-what-structures-can-a-rescue-statement-be-nested-in), as well as [the dupe above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542672/how-does-one-use-rescue-in-rails-without-the-begin-and-end-block).

Answer (score 2):

**rescue** can work alone . no need of begin and end always .

You can use rescue in its single line form to return a value when other things on the line go awry:

```
h = { :age => 10 }
h[:name].downcase                         # ERROR
h[:name].downcase rescue "No name"
```

Comment: This uses it as a statement modifier, though, which isn't the OP's question. You're correct, of course, but it doesn't directly answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

`rescue` word is part of method definition

But in controllers better to rescue errors with `rescue_from`

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
def edit
  begin
    load_elements(current_user) unless current_user.role?(:admin)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @user }   
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
      format.html
    end

  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    respond_to_not_found(:json, :xml, :html)
  end
end
```

Comment: It's perfectly legal to use a `rescue` inside a method definition (and implicit `begin`) without an explicit `begin`.